# Could not get the Domain User

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, single-sign-on

I have the following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string infors = "";
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity usr = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        infors += "Authentication Type: " + usr.AuthenticationType + "<br>";
        infors += "Name: " + usr.Name + "<br>";
        infors += "IsAnonymous: " + usr.IsAnonymous + "<br>";
        infors += "IsAuthenticated: " + usr.IsAuthenticated + "<br>";
        infors += "IsGuest: " + usr.IsGuest + "<br>";
        infors += "IsSystem: " + usr.IsSystem + "<br>";
        infors += "Token: " + usr.Token.ToString() + "<br>";

        Label1.Text = infors;
    }
```

However, it keep giving me the wrong information on the `Name` part

```
Authentication Type: NTLM
Name: SECTOR_A\Administrator
IsAnonymous: False
IsAuthenticated: True
IsGuest: False
IsSystem: False
Token: 564
```

My IIS is set to:

```
Anonymous Authentication - Disabled
ASP.NET Impersonation - Enabled
Basic Authentication - Enabled
Windows Authentication - Enabled
```

and I even change the IE setting by setting to `Prompt for user name and password` as shown below

[image]

**====== However ======**

Although I enter the the Domain username and password in the popup login message when I open the web application, it did not give me the correct `Name` part, which should be `SECTOR_HQ\Jack`.

So I would like to ask if there are anything missing in my code and configurations.

**====== Added the Web.config ======**

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**====== Application Pool Info ======**

```
.NET Framework Version: v4.0
Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic
Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity
```

Comment: Can you show your authentication section in web.config?

Comment: @2GDev, Thanks, I have added to the question for your infor.

Comment: Why don't you use `this.User` property?

Comment: @JakubKonecki, it return me `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal`

Comment: @Jack - Yes, that's the principal you want, It has `Identity` property. You should prefer using this property rather than `WindowsIdentity` directly.

Comment: @JakubKonecki, I tried your `this.User.Identity` and it return me `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity`

Comment: Which App pool is the site using.   Check the Advanced tab page for the pool.  Please add what the indentity settings for the used APP pool are.

Comment: @soadyp, Thanks, I have added to the question for your info.

Answer (score 0):

Try add the authentication section in your config :

```
 <system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    ...
 </system.web>
```

Here you can find more details :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: Great, now I am able to see the domain user. However, there is a problem is that when I am logged into the PC using the domain username, it still prompt me for username and password. Is there anywhere to skip it if the user have login to the PC using the domain username and password?

Comment: By the way, the link you provided is for ASP.NET 2, not the one that I am using .NET 4. Does it still able to apply for .NET 4?

Comment: @Jack maybe on your IE options you've to set the "Automatic Logon with current username and password". 
I can't find any difference about asp.net 2.0 and 4.0 authentication settings. I will check if there is any.